# Redirect from old url to new url patron

Tags: .htaccess

I want to add multiple redirect old website urls to new urls

Currently I have this url pattren

http://example.com/product/cat1/cat2/61600

I want to redirect all pages with the above pattern with the below one

http://example2.com/canbenaything-61600.html

However I want to redirect all urls on Last url part based on this case it is 61600.

Comment: Show us what you tried, describe what the specific problem was.

Comment: Your question is unlcear: when redirecting the client, will the "cat1" and "cat2" data get lost, that is fine? And where does that "canbeanything" prefix come from? Is it fixed?

Comment: Well this part of the url /product/cat1/cat2/61600 is dynamic and we have only last part of the url 61600 in old url that can be match with our new url structure canbenaything-61600.html.
Just we have to match the last part of url  in this case is 61600 with new url  structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, add this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^product/cat1/cat2/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example2\.com\/canbenaything-$1.html" [R=301,L]
```

The following line will match the example.com which is a rewrite condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
```

The following line will match the query string after `product/cat1/cat2/(.*)` and store what is there in place of `(.*)`

```
RewriteRule ^product/cat1/cat2/(.*)$
```

And the complete line will redirect to new URL

```
RewriteRule ^product/cat1/cat2/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example2\.com\/canbenaything-$1.html" [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect http://example.com/anything/some_id to http://example2.com/something_else-some_id.html

then the following line would work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example2\.com\/something_else-$2.html" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you . I got it working with some modifications  here is my final line of the htaccess rule

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$4-$5.html [R=301,L]